# CompletionService vs CompletableFuture

Tags: java, multithreading, java.util.concurrent, completable-future, completion-service

I have 1000 big files to be processed in order as mentioned below:

1. First those files needs to be copied to a different directory in parallel, I am planning to use `ExecutorService` with 10 threads to achieve it.
2. As soon as any file is copied to another location(#1), I will submit that file for further processing to `ExecutorService` with 10 threads.
3. And finally, another action needs to be performed on these files in parallel, like #2 gets input from #1, #3 gets input from #2.

Now, I can use `CompletionService` here, so I can process the thread results from #1 to #2 and #2 to #3 in the order they are getting completed. `CompletableFuture` says we can chain asynchronous tasks together which sounds like something I can use in this case.

I am not sure if I should implement my solution with `CompletableFuture` (since it is relatively new and ought to be better) or if `CompletionService` is sufficient? And why should I chose one over another in this case?

Comment: what do you mean by " #2 gets input from #1,  #3 gets input from #2"?

Comment: @AlexeiKaigorodov - I meant as soon as step 1 tasks finish, the result of those tasks gets consumed by step 2.

Comment: what are the steps 1,2, etc?

Answer (score 1):

It would probably be best if you tried both approaches and then choose the one you are more comfortable with. Though it sounds like `CompletableFuture`s are better suited for this task because they make chaining processing steps / stages really easy. For example in your case the code could look like this:

```java
ExecutorService copyingExecutor = ...
// Not clear from the requirements, but let's assume you have
// a separate executor for this
ExecutorService processingExecutor = ...

public CompletableFuture<MyResult> process(Path file) {
    return CompletableFuture
        .supplyAsync(
            () -> {
                // Retrieve destination path where file should be copied to
                Path destination = ...
                try {
                    Files.copy(file, destination);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    throw new UncheckedIOException(e);
                }
                return destination;
            },
            copyingExecutor
        )
        .thenApplyAsync(
            copiedFile -> {
                // Process the copied file
                ...
            },
            processingExecutor
        )
        // This separate stage does not make much sense, so unless you have
        // yet another executor for this or this stage is applied at a different
        // location in your code, it should probably be merged with the
        // previous stage
        .thenApply(
            previousResult -> {
                // Process the previous result
                ...
            }
        );
}
```